# PrestaShop returns 302 in webservice

Tags: php, prestashop

I have following problem my presta shop is returning:

Other error:
This call to PrestaShop Web Services returned an unexpected HTTP status of:302

and the code is:

```
<html><head><title>CRUD Tutorial - Customer's list</title></head><body>
<?php
define('DEBUG', true);                                          // Debug mode
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', "http://127.0.0.1");     // Root path of your PrestaShop store
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'some auth key');  // Auth key (Get it in your Back Office)
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
try
{   

    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $opt['resource'] = 'products';

    $xml = $webService->get($opt);
    echo $xml;
    $resources = $xml->customers->children();
    echo $resources;
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
{
  echo 'Other error: <br />' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
</body></html>
```

I think everything is configured properly: webservices are enabled,auth key is generated but where can be issue?